# sophisticated concrete types copy value cause glibc errors

Tags: c++, copy

```
#include "iostream"

class Vector {
private:
    double *elem; // elem points to an array of sz doubles
    int sz;
public:

    Vector(int s);  // constructor: establish invariant, acquire resources
    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor: release resources
    Vector(const Vector &a); // copy constr uctor
    Vector &operator=(const Vector &a); // copy assignment
    double &operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
};

Vector::Vector(const Vector &a) // copy constr uctor
        : elem{new double[sz]}, // allocate space for elements
          sz{a.sz} {
    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) // copy elements
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}

Vector &Vector::operator=(const Vector &a) // copy assignment
{
    std::cout << "xxx" << std::endl;
    double *p = new double[a.sz];
    for (int i = 0; i != a.sz; ++i)
        p[i] = a.elem[i];
    delete[] elem; // delete old elements
    elem = p;
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
}

Vector::Vector(int s)  :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }

int main() {
    Vector v1{4};
    Vector v2 = v1; // copy v1’s representation into v2
    v1[0] = 2; // v2[0] is now also 2!
    v2[1] = 3;
    std::cout << " success " << std::endl;
}
```

the rusult is:
Fatal glibc error: malloc assertion failure in sysmalloc: (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)
why error occurs?which code cause errors

Comment: Keep staring at the following, until you see the obvious bug: `elem{new double[sz]}, sz{a.sz} {`. Hint: this kind of a bug is called "putting the cart before the horse".

Comment: And/or use std::make_unique<double[]>() and std::unique_ptr reset to get rid of your naked new/deletes (much easier to avoid memory allocation bugs/leaks).

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik ,what is  the right code

Comment: Do you understand how member initialization syntax works, in C++? If you do, then the bug, and the "right code" should be obvious. If you don't, then this is something that can't be explained in just a few sentences, see your C++ textbook for more information.